# opencv : how to use specific functions such as flip() for my own projects

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, porting

I'm using openCV and have got a project at hand. Here I need to extract only the required methods such as flip(), GaussianBlur() etc., which are used in our projects so that later we may optimize them for specific hardware.

What the trouble is: I started by porting flip(). I copied the code and it gave some errors. I debugged them, plugged in the required headers etc. But this process seems to be unending.

Also I searched stackoverflow but no use. Can anyone guide me in the right direction. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do? Do you just aim to re-code some opencv functions?

Comment: Not recode but put a local copy of the implementation of some specific functions.... Which we want to later optimise for particular hardware.

Comment: Also the main aim is to remove the dependency from opencv library... Isolating the required functions only. Plan is to use multi threading to speed-up the code. Also hardware specific instructions to be used in later optimizations.

Comment: With out you code its hard to tell anything...

Comment: Let me explain in detail... We have got a file where we call an opencv function say, GaussianBlur(). This call currently needs opencv to be executed. What all should  be done to remove this dependency without implementing the said function. The idea is to make a local copy of all the required files so as to make the function call work.